# sails.js waterline model not working

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have the next two models:

```
module.exports = {
    identity: 'WebsiteWidget',
    attributes: {
        name: 'string',
        type: {
          type: 'string',
          enum: ['fullPage', 'container', 'base']
        },
        container: {
          model: 'container'
        },
        widget: {
          model: 'widget'
        },
        page: {
          model: 'page'
        },
        data: {
          type: 'json'
        },
        output: {
          type: 'text'
        },
        widgetHtml: {
            model: 'widgethtml'
        },
        sort: 'integer'
    }
}

module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        widget: 'string',
        templateName: 'string',
        source: 'text',
        settings: 'json'
    }
};
```

The thing is that `WebsiteWidget` holds an `id` of `WidgetHtml`, when i execute a find query, the `websiteHtml` property returns just the `id` instead of the whole `WidgetHtml` model.
What is the problem?

Comment: Give us the code of your find request please

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly tell waterline to retrieve your WidgetHtml like :

```
WebsiteWidget.find(....).populate("widgetHtml").exec(function(err, website))
{

//Do what you want 

});
```

Comment: This is the solution; though I'd recommend using promises (`.then()`) instead of `.exec()`

Comment: I did figure out that the problem might be with the populate on my query, my problem is doing nested queries, as i understood waterline doesn't support nested queries, is there a good way to the nested populates that doesn't require me to run a query on each of my results?

Comment: Yes you can use async and make your nested queries

Comment: can you send me an example code, all examples I've seen are conserning a findOne query, I have a find query that brings me multiple results

Answer (score 0):

Use **[populate()](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/queries/populate.html)** or **[populateAll()](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/queries/populateAll.html)** from Sails.js Waterline.

Comment: read my comment on the previous answer, it will be great if you can give me the example i'm looking for